# If Get-ADGroupMember does not find disable users .. say

Tags: powershell

Sorry for this dumb question, it is late at night and my brain does not work.
The following script find the disable users from a specific account, and put them in a HTML page table (Name and SamAccountName).
I just want to say, if the group does not have a disable account say.... "Not disable accounts in this group" instead of showing an empty area.

```
$NuixAdmins = Get-ADGroupMember “NUIX-ADMIN” |
    Where { -not ((Get-ADUser $_.samAccountName).Enabled) } | 
    ConvertTo-Html -Property SamAccountName, Name -Fragment -PreContent "<h2>Nuix Admins</h2>"
```

I was thinking a....

```
If ($NuixAdmins.Count -eq 0) {Write-Host 'No Disable Users'}
```

I dont think this works because when i say $NuixAdmin.Count, it shows 3, but all of those users are ENABLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice you against `Get-ADGroupMember`, it's slow and sometimes prone to errors.

Note, I'm assuming you want to find only those members that are `user objects`, hence why `Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter` if you want to find all `object class` use `Get-ADObject`

Try with this:

```
$groupDN = (Get-ADGroup “NUIX-ADMIN”).distinguishedName
$members = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(memberof=$groupDN)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))"

if(-not $members)
{
    Write-Host 'No Disabled Users'
}
else
{
    $members | ConvertTo-Html -Property SamAccountName, Name -Fragment -PreContent "<h2>Nuix Admins</h2>"
}
```

---

**Edit**

To explain the LDAPFilter:

- `(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)`: Refers to **Disabled** objects.
- `(memberOf=cn=Test,ou=East,dc=Domain,dc=com)`: All direct members of specified group.
- `&`: AND, all conditions must be met.

To know more about this please read: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx

---

This is what I would personally do using `Get-ADGroupMember`:

```
$members = Get-ADGroupMember “NUIX-ADMIN” | Where-Object { $_.ObjectClass -eq 'User' }
$result = foreach($member in $members)
{
    $user = Get-ADUser $member

    if(-not $user.Enaled)
    {
        $user
    }
}

if($result)
{
    $result | ConvertTo-Html -Property SamAccountName, Name -Fragment -PreContent "<h2>Nuix Admins</h2>"
}
else
{
    Write-Host 'No Disabled Users'
}
```

Comment: Hello Santiago,
Thank you for your help!, the script does not show Disable Users, it shows all (Disable and Enable)

Comment: @Miguel Woops, my bad! I edited the code, let me know if it works :)

Comment: it works, thank you so much!
Could you explain what is "userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)" ?
Also... why doesnt my script work? how can I do the same using my script?  Just curiosity :)

Comment: @Miguel of course, I added 2 edits, check them out.

Comment: No problem @Miguel, happy to help!